# JPA Select only one of each value in one column

Tags: jpa, jpql

I have a list like:

```
Name       Age
Charles    18
Anna       20
Anna       19
Tomas      44
Karla      13
Charles    88
```

I would write a JPQL statement that give me:

```
Charles    18
Anna       20
Tomas      44
Karla      13
```

In other words, how can I get a list with unique names where the age dont care?

Best regards

Carl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really don't care about the age, don't select it:

```
select distinct u.name from User u
```

If you'd like to get a valid age with each user, but don't care which one, select the min or max of the ages:

```
select u.name, max(u.age) from User u group by u.name
```